# How do I add a querystring to show user language (?lang=es-MX) using IIS7 Rewrite 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-6

I have a website (Visual Studio / VB / ASP.NET 4.0) and I have it localized with 9 different languages, so 9 different .resx files in my Apps_GlobalResources directory.  The **languages works great**, and the end-user may manually select the language they want to view.

**The Problem:**

When a user is on the home page, for example, they're on domain/default.aspx.  When they switch to Spanish - Mexican, the page switches to spanish-Mexican, but **the URL stays the same -- domain/default.aspx**.

It's been recommended by many that I show the end user a querystring.  So I want the URL to look like **domain/default.aspx?lang=es-MX** or **domain//es-MX/default.aspx** (preferred).

Since all my resource files are in place, **can I accomplish this via the II7 rewrite tool**?  If so, can somebody please explain how I can go about doing it?  I'm not familiar with negotiating IIS.  Thank you and I'd sincerely appreciate any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

you can modify web.config files and it'll handle the rewrite for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="^(.*)-htm-(.*)" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php?{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/show-([0-9]+)([\-])?([0-9]+)?\.html" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/show.php?itemid={R:2}&page={R:4}"  />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/list-([0-9]+)([\-])?([0-9]+)?\.html" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/list.php?catid={R:2}&page={R:4}"  />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/show/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?([/])?" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/show.php?itemid={R:2}&page={R:3}"  />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/list/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?([/])?" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/list.php?catid={R:2}&page={R:3}"  />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([a-z0-9]+)\.co/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="company/index.php?homepage={R:1}&rewrite={R:2}"  />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule7" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(htm)/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?rewrite={R:2}"  />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

here's something you can read:
http://gyansangrah.com/ArticleContent.aspx?ID=URLREWRITINGUSINGHTTPMODULES

Comment: Hi Jim!  Thank you for your time and your answer.  My site is in asp.net 4.0, and I've actually created a rewrite map so that the .aspx extension doesn't show up.  So when I go to my contact page, it's just domain.com/contact, but what I'm really trying to do is to find a way to negotiate the rewrite so that when a user picks a language, it shows up in the URL. So domain.com/contact?lang=ja-JA or something.  I do appreciate you taking the time to repsond, but I think I need a different solution, as modifying my web.config that way wouldn't help achieve my objective.  Thanks again, appreciated!

Comment: Jason, maybe you have a landing page where user can select the language and append the language in the query string from there?! If not so, maybe such information can be appended when an user selects any language. Maybe you're looking for an automatic way to auto append such information in the query string? I'm not sure such thing exist. My approach is to check for query string for language information first, if it doesn't exist, it'll be appeneded (from session perhaps)